# Cannot initialize shared_ptr

Tags: qt, shared-ptr

I've `shared_ptr <QMap < T , X > * > shared_` and I'm trying to initialize it like this:

```
shared_t = new QMap < T , X >();
```

but I'm getting error:

```
    c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\shared_ptr_base.h:762: error: cannot  
 convert 'QMap<boost::filesystem3::path, Qt::CheckState>*' to 'QMap<boost::filesystem3::path,    
   Qt::CheckState>**' in initialization
```

How am I supposed to initialize this ptr? Please note that I do need pointer to map as a type stored in shared_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type in the template parameter has to be the value type itself, not a pointer to it:

```
shared_ptr <QMap<T, X> > shared_t;
```

Comment: #Steve, so basically I cannot have a pointer to pointer? Not the most flexible approach. Thanks.